# Alembic version in database is not in the version history

Tags: postgresql, alembic, flask-migrate

According to [Alembic's docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#running-our-first-migration), the migration algorithm is trying to calculate the migration "path" to target revision from the version it finds in the `alembic_version` table. Upon checking that in the db of the service I'm working with, I found out that the current version that Alembic operates from is not in the version history, i.e. there is no migration script in projects `migrations` folder with that revision ID.

It seems that for this reason, when I added a manually written migration script (with empty template from `alembic revision`), calling `alembic upgrade` with this revision's ID failed silently without carrying out the migration. I got an output ending with

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

and exit code 1.

However, when I changed the value in `alembic_version` table to the penultimate version ID (the one revised by my own script), `alembic upgrade head` worked.

It is unclear whether or not the database actually was in the state corresponding with the revision ID I set manually. The script I migrated with only creates a table like this:

```
...
import sqlalchemy as sa
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql as pg

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '09d841dcd114'
down_revision = '450e39fe439d'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

def upgrade():
    op.create_table('table_name',
        sa.Column('id', pg.UUID(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
        sa.Column('user_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    ...
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['other_schema.users.id'], name='schemaname_tablename_user_id_fkey'),
        schema='schema_name'
    )
...
```

so it's partly reliant on existing database state, but does not determine the state exacly.

So my question is: is it normally possible that the `alembic_version` in db is not among existing revisions? Was that the reason why my previous attempts to migrate the db failed silently? What would be the correct solution for this problem? Setting the alembic version manually feels like an improper way to deal with this.

The alembic commands here were mostly given using Flask-Migrate, but it seems to not affect anything in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a hotfix revision not merged into the main branch, but used on the service. That's where the missing version was